# Can empty empty function be fully optimized by JS engine?

Tags: javascript, optimization, arguments

I'm working on a framework and would like to do some error checking at development time, but skip this during production time. The reason for this checks upfront are, that eg. argument 1 should always be an object of a given constructor. If this is the case, further checks can be omitted eg. presents of properties.

At the beginning of a function I'm adding a call to

```
check(functionIdentifier, arguments)
```

On production sites I would use an empty check function to increase performance.

I have read that arguments should only be used, if needed, because it is hard to optimize by JS engines. So I wonder, if JS engines are able to optimize, if check is an empty function and arguments is not used in any why except for calling the empty function. **Are there alternatives for dynamic type checking, that are much faster when omitted?**

The following is really error-prone during programming, because it is very easy to make copy-paste-failures.

```
check(functionIdentifier, argument1, argument2, argument3)
```

Worst case would be that argument4 is missing but undefined is valid, while a string isn't. Another very common issue would be that an argument is mistyped

Here is an example:

```
// in main.js file
function check(){
}

function a(argument1, argument2){
  check(a, arguments);
  // ...
}

// in check.js, which is loaded after main.js and only during development
// so it replaces the check function in the window context
function check(functionIdentifier, arguments){
  switch(functionIdentifier){
    case a:
      // do some checks with arguments
      if(!ok) 
        throw new TypeErrow(/* some information */);
      break;
    case b:
      // ...
  }
}
```

Comment: Typescript maybe? 

Comment: Typescript does the job. However, it is no longer native JS and needs to be transpiled before. So not really an option.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say that an empty function call could theoretically be optimized away, *but* most engines will probably not do this, as having an empty function in the code is very, very uncommon and therefore there is no performance improvement through this optimization. Maybe (pure speculation) it will optimize away the unised parameters / arguments and inline the function, which will completely optimize away the function call. But even then, does that nanosecond spent on the function call really matter?

Comment: I've just added a `checkCounter`. During startup for a small test application it reaches just above 10,000 calls. After a couple of seconds it reaches 30,000. It doesn't matter on desktop computers, but on mobile devices it could.

Answer (score 0):

I've used JSPerf and tried some browsers. Chrome and Opera optimizing very well. Firefox (99 % slower), Edge (99 % slower), and Safari (96 % slower) are slowing down drastically.

So the answer to the title is: **No**. Some are nearby eg. Chrome. Others are far off.

**But are there good alternatives for dynamic type checking and omitting it?**

Here is [JSPerf](https://jsperf.com/arguments-optimzation)